# Thread data encapsulation best practices

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have a question how to encapsulate data gracefully in such case.
Let's think we want to make some class that can asynchronous download images from internet. Let us have unblocking method:

```
void download(string url)
```

This method will create thread and start downloading, and then invoke callback:

```
void callback(char* data)
```

What is best: allocate memory for data in Downloader or allocate it out of Downloader class? In first case we will need to copy data returned in callback and if data is big - it is not good, otherwise we will allocate memory in Downloader class and release it somewhere else. In second case we need to allocate memory for data and pass it as parameter in download method:

```
char *data = new char[DATA_SIZE];
downloader.download(url, data);
```

But how can we protect this allocated data from changing it from callable thread, while it used by downloader thread. I think there is some way to make it without synchronization in callable thread some way to make this logic invisible for client.

Hope you get my mind right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some sprinkling of C++ Standard Library classes would probably be good.

```
std::future<std::vector<unsigned char>> download(std::string url) {
    std::promise<std::vector<unsigned char>> promise;
    std::future<std::vector<unsigned char>> future = promise.get_future();
    //I'm like 99% certain that both promise and future ref-count their shared state
    //so it's probably safe to move and later even delete the promise object.
    func_which_begins_asynchronous_process(url, std::move(promise));
    return future;
}

void callback(std::vector<unsigned char> data, std::promise<std::vector<unsigned char>> promise) {
    promise.set_value(std::move(data));
}

int main() {
    auto future = download("google.com");
    //Do whatever
    std::vector<unsigned char> result = future.get();
    //Do whatever
    return 0;
}
```

This will both make the code easy to reason about, and will reliably handle the "pointer ownership" issue you discussed in your original post.

I don't know the exact semantics/requirements of your code, so my code won't work in your solution "as-is", but this should give you a pretty good idea of the kind of paradigm that will solve your problem.

Comment: I saw advices on similar problems - smart pointers and C++11 are best way to solve them. Thanks for answer!